# bower_components to build for my project are too large

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, bower, gulp-uglify

After my gulp build my project using this node js code

```
gulp.task('build-css-js-files', function() {
    return  gulp.src('app/*.html')
        .pipe(useref())
        .pipe(gulpif('*.js', uglify()))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist));
});
```

it returns this warning message:

```
[21:10:48] Starting 'build-css-js-files'...
WARN: Output exceeds 32000 characters
WARN: Output exceeds 32000 characters
WARN: Output exceeds 32000 characters
WARN: Output exceeds 32000 characters
WARN: Output exceeds 32000 characters
WARN: Output exceeds 32000 characters
WARN: Output exceeds 32000 characters
[21:14:10] Finished 'build-css-js-files' after 3.35 min
```

Please is there any possible way i can divide the build process into two or more seqments. To prevent me from having a very large vendor.js file.

Here is my bower component which i wish to divide into two:

```
<!-- build:js js/vendors.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-google-gapi/dist/angular-google-gapi.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/jquery-knob/js/jquery.knob.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-loading-bar/build/loading-bar.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/trix/dist/trix.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-trix/dist/angular-trix.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-select/dist/select.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-tag/dist/angular-tag.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-button-spinner/dist/angular-button-spinner.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/rangy/rangy-core.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/rangy/rangy-classapplier.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/rangy/rangy-highlighter.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/rangy/rangy-selectionsaverestore.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/rangy/rangy-serializer.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/rangy/rangy-textrange.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/textAngular/dist/textAngular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/textAngular/dist/textAngular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/textAngular/dist/textAngularSetup.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-sortable/sortable.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/pdfmake/build/pdfmake.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap-calendar/dist/js/angular-bootstrap-calendar-tpls.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/rrule/lib/rrule.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/jquery-mousewheel/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Comment: It's okay to have a large *single file* than having *multiple files* that accounts the same size as the *single file*. The reason is to avoid the browser from creating multiple **HTTP** requests and results in a poor website performance.

Comment: After the compile, i guess there is a conflict in some part of the code and am finding it difficult to target the source of the error and solve it. So i believe if i can divide the build into two i will be able to see the part that have the error.

Comment: Beside, the un-uglify version of the code does not have the error, it is only the compile uglify one.

Comment: do not understand your problem clearly. Is it warning itself? How about this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43532310/4075138 ?

Comment: i want to have two uglify file after build. Instead of vendor.js alone, i want vendor1.js, vendor2.js so that i will be able to trace any error that come up.